# How to get an access to Google Drive API service account from web browser

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

I use "Service account" method for using Google Drive API.
I need to get an access to my storage through Web browser to make a folder structure and have an ability to change/remove/add files quickly without calling API commands.
Is there an ability to login under xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com account? Or are there any other ways?

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: I have found a solution that works for me. I created a folder in my main Google account (that I use for Google Drive API access) and shared it with my API's email address - xxx@developer.gserviceaccount.com.
Now I'm working with this folder through both a Web browser (from my Google account) and API requests and all changes are synced.
Maybe it will help someone.

Comment: Hello @Victor..I want to share my google drive acount(or some file through google drive account) to my website for all internet user.I think you did just the same.Can you please help me in that..from last few days I am trying this..Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

You may like to take a look at JWT JavaScript implementations such as jwt-js [1] to reimplement the service account auth flow [2].

1. https://github.com/michaelrhanson/jwt-js
2. https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2ServiceAccount