# Is it possible to use the Google Drive API only with Javascript and without Node.JS?

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I saw that is possible Upload files using that API through VB.Net and C# for Desktop applications and Node.js, ASP Net for Web applications but I need to know if its possible to achieve it only with Javascript (No node.js) in front end.

Ps: I want to upload files to a Google Drive Service Account.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload files using Javascript alone, you probably can do in Google Scripts using the Drive Service. Here are two links which might help:

[- Drive Service in Google Scripts](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/)

[- Google App Scripts Quickstart to call the Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/quickstart/apps-script)

Answer (score 0):

Certainly.

---

### Goole JavaScript client library

> You can use the JavaScript client library to interact with Google
>   APIs, such as People, Calendar, and Drive, from your web applications. *(developers.google.com)*

You need to import the Google API Client Library first.

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js"></script>
```

...and initialize it:

```
function start() {
  // 2. Initialize the JavaScript client library.
    gapi.client.init({
    'apiKey': 'YOUR_API_KEY',
    // Your API key will be automatically added to the Discovery Document URLs.
    'discoveryDocs': ['https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest'],
    // clientId and scope are optional if auth is not required.
    'clientId': 'YOUR_WEB_CLIENT_ID.apps.googleusercontent.com',
    'scope': 'profile',
  }).then( /* your requests go HERE */ )
};
// 1. Load the JavaScript client library.
gapi.load('client', start);
```

...to finally proceed with your requests.

---

### Links :

In the **Quickstart - Javascript** documentation page, you will find a simple example of the Drive API usage.
https://developers.google.com/drive/v3/web/quickstart/js

And all the detals about the **Javascript client library** in :
https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/javascript/start/start-js

Comment: Thank you colxi, I saw the quickstart google documentation but I'm trying to achieve it for a service account, I don't know what changes I can make to avoid asking the user for his permission. Sorry if I'm not seeing it yet.

Comment: ups... i didn't pay attemtion to the  'Service Account' detail. Take a look to the answer to this question  : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17278744/1473968